# Appium error while trying to run appium by genymotion emulator

Tags: appium, genymotion

I tried to run appium in genymotion emulator but it throws the error couldn't prelaunch... can you please explain the way how to use genymotion emulator in the appium..

error:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] 

[debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
info: [debug] Checking app cert for /Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/Driverapk.apk.
info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-adb/jars/verify.jar "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/Driverapk.apk"

info: [debug] App already signed.

info: [debug] Zip-aligning /Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/Driverapk.apk
info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
info: [debug] Using zipalign from /Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/zipalign

info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/zipalign" -f 4 "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/Driverapk.apk" /var/folders/0y/h2nghs4x06db8r6t44gdhmgh0000gp/T/11712-799-ifdvf/appium.tmp

info: [debug] MD5 for app is b69f7c349220ba35d0b055339f2ea909

info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/b69f7c349220ba35d0b055339f2ea909.apk"

info: [debug] Getting install status for com.Taximobility.driver

info: [debug] Getting device API level
info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"

info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19

info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell "pm list packages -3 com.Taximobility.driver"

info: [debug] App is not installed

info: Installing App
info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell "mkdir -p /data/local/tmp/"

info: [debug] Removing any old apks

info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/*.apk"

info: [debug] Found an apk we want to keep at /data/local/tmp/b69f7c349220ba35d0b055339f2ea909.apk

info: [debug] Couldn't find any apks to remove
info: [debug] Uninstalling com.Taximobility.driver
info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell "am force-stop com.Taximobility.driver"

info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 uninstall com.Taximobility.driver

info: [debug] App was not uninstalled, maybe it wasn't on device?

info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell "pm install -r /data/local/tmp/b69f7c349220ba35d0b055339f2ea909.apk"

warn: Installing remote apk failed, going to uninstall and try again

info: [debug] Removing any old apks
info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/*.apk"

info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell rm "/data/local/tmp/b69f7c349220ba35d0b055339f2ea909.apk"

info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 push "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/Driverapk.apk" /data/local/tmp/b69f7c349220ba35d0b055339f2ea909.apk

info: [debug] Attempting to install again for the last time

info: [debug] executing cmd: "/Users/developer/Desktop/Mohan testing/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell "pm install -r /data/local/tmp/b69f7c349220ba35d0b055339f2ea909.apk"

info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture

info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM

info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...

warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone

error: Could not pre-launch appium: Error: Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/b69f7c349220ba35d0b055339f2ea909.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting option> And Uncheck the prelaunch checkbox of appium